# What's the Java 9+ replacement for Sun's VirtualListViewControl?

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I maintain a codebase that uses `com.sun.jndi.ldap.ctl.VirtualListViewControl` from the old Sun LDAP Booster Pack, and I'm trying to update it to Java 11 standard.

The first issue is that when trying to compile the code you get:

`...] cannot access com.sun.jndi.ldap.BasicControl
  class file for com.sun.jndi.ldap.BasicControl not found`

This can be fixed by adding the following to the compiler args:

`--add-exports java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED`

This allows the Booster Pack code on the classpath to access the internal `com.sun.jndi.ldap.BasicControl` in the `java.naming` module, and everything works.

However, using `--add-exports` is ugly and, more pertinently, is incompatible with using the `--release` option to ensure you build to a particular code level and API.

I've been hunting around but I can't seem to find anything resembling either an updated/modularized ldapbp or an alternative implementation of a VLV control.

So my question is: What is the official or accepted replacement for Sun's old `VirtualListViewControl` that plays nicely with Java 9+, or is there another way of using the old one that doesn't require `--add-exports`?

Comment: I'm not certain, No experience with ldap. But will the Javax classes work? https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.naming/javax/naming/ldap/BasicControl.html

Comment: @Dylan `PagedResultsControl` from the booster pack was added to the `javax.naming.ldap` package in Java 5, but `VirtualListViewControl` was not, and there is nothing equivalent in there.